# how to log resource bundle key missing

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

I am using http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt tag library for outputting messages from Message Resource Bundle which is set up in Spring configuration. Also message resolving can go in Controllers.

I would like to log situations when the keys are not found in resource bundle file.

Does any body know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses a `MessageSource` to retrieve the messages so one solution could be to write your own `MessageSource` that encapsulate the Spring one and overwrite the `getMessage` methods to insert your logging.

Something like the following (not tested):

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="com.acme.LoggingMessageSource">
   <property name="pathtru">
     <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basenames">
         <list>
           <value>buttons</value>
           <value>labels</value>
         </list>    
       </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

with the class:

```
public class LoggingMessageSource implements MessageSource {

  private MessageSource pathtru;

  public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
    // ...
  }

  public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
    // ...
  }

  public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I don't know if some methods are calling the other ones so you will have to experiment a bit.